# How to make a 40mH inductor

Tags: inductor

We are working on a project that requires us to use a high-valued inductor, with at least 10mH and ideally 40mH inductance.

There's nowhere in our area that sells inductors with these values, so we concluded that we should make one ourselves, but all attempts we've made using small ferrites lead us to a max value of 0.5mH, which is way off.

So, how can I make an inductance value this large without having to wire 10000 turns of coil?

EDIT: It's for a theremin project, frequency is around 200-300kHz

[image]

Comment: What is the nature of the signal that the inductor will be carrying? What's the frequency of the signal? It's impossible to design an inductor without knowing more about the application.

Comment: What are your specs for resistance and saturation current?  What's the frequency of the inductor current?  You will need a high permeability material for that kind of inductance, maybe a silicon steel toroid core or even an amorphous tape wound core.

Comment: I wound one with 100 turns ish on an RM12 pot core once. Maybe it was an RM10 core and I think the ferrite was 3C85. However, there was no dc current in this application and the p-p voltage I could get across it without significant saturation below 10 Hz was probably around 5 volts.

Comment: I edited the OP concerning application and frequency specs. Saturation current and resistance I have no idea, but since it's a very low current I dont think it should be a problem

Comment: Ah, that's different from the way I was thinking earlier. Sounds like a high permeability ferrite is the way to go since there's no concern about sustaining lots of volt-seconds, and the frequency is relatively high.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, trolling digikey it looks like anything over ~10mH has a SRF above or near your working frequency.  Maybe a few 10mH in series.  Since I assume you are "resonating" your ~10-100pF antenna some inductor with "taps" might be useful.    As a crazy idea how about an opamp gyrator circuit.  (I've never made one, but always wanted to.)  I'm guessing you'd want a fairly fast opamp, maybe an AD825.

Answer (score 1):

This might help http://www.arrl.org/files/file/Technology/tis/info/pdf/9708033.pdf, it has illustration and example.